# Is this a valid method for setting a value to "true" in Scratch?

Tags: mit-scratch

So I have started to create a [Plants v.s Zombies mod in Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/844867116/). My main concern right now is attempting to figure out how to code a drag and drop system (i.e. clicking the seed packet and then drag and dropping it), but when I attempt to make it work when I start the project, it doesn't seem to work, since I can only seem to drag the seed packet for some reason, even with turning the seed packet dragging off.

What I have tried (scratchblocks format):

---

When I click the seed packet

```
[scratchblocks]
when this sprite clicked
Greater than or equal to (var) (number)
[/scratchblocks]
```

[image]

A possible way I could simplify the "if `var` is greater than or equal to `number`" code to use less blocks

```
[scratchblocks]
define Greater than or equal to(var)(number)
if <(var) > (number)> then 
broadcast [message 1 v]
else
end
[/scratchblocks]
```

[image]

For when the plant that I am making a clone of receives the specific message.

```
[scratchblocks]
when I receive [message 1 v]
create clone of [myself v]
[/scratchblocks]
```

[image]

The code for the clone (dragging and dropping it [test])

```
[scratchblocks]
when I start as a clone
if <<mouse down?> = [true]> then 
  show
set [brightness v] effect to (40)
go to x: (mouse x) y: (mouse y)
else
delete this clone
end
[/scratchblocks]
```

[image]

---

**My question**

---

What am I doing wrong that would cause the code to be like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues in your code.

1. You never initialize your `peashooter cost` variable, so it's NOT greater or equal to 100.
2. The `mouse down` is a boolean variable, and it is never equal to an empty string. You should compare it to `false`.
3. In your `when I start as a clone` block - why do you have a `forever` block? As soon as you release the mouse button, the clone will be shown, the code will proceed to the next iteration of that `forever`, and since the mouse is no longer down - you would delete that clone!

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that my `peashooter cost` was never initialized, I honestly would not have caught that mistake if it weren't for this answer

Answer (score 1):

A way to simplify the "if var is greater than or equal to number" code would be to use [this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd0ID.png)

if <not <(var) < (number)>>

`a >= b` is the same thing as `a !< b`